# Update configured themes

Tags: multisite, themes

**Background:**

We've inherited care of a WP Networks install with many individualized sites. Most of them have some type of directly customized theme. If I begin updating themes, clients will lose customization. We've since disallowed direct theme customization; opting instead for child themes. Going forward we'll be okay; however, I need to tackle these legacy sites.

**Question:**

How might I update themes in place and at the same time save and/or re-implement clients' customization? I will need something that I can automate at some point.

**Brainstorm:**

My first idea was to download the currently running version of their theme from a codeplex and do a diff across both folders. Next activate that unaltered version in the unaltered theme and moving the diff'ed files to a child theme. Once that is in place, I'll issue `wp theme update --all`.

But I still fear this will be a load of manual work.

Comment: I think your brainstorm is the best option. You should get them all child themes and then going forward it will be way less of a hassle to update. It shouldn't take too long. Just figure out which files were customized, through them in a child theme, back up the customized parent theme just in case, and then update the parent theme. Then it should be way better. Not only will you need to do a long manual theme update but in the future you can just update instead of transferring customizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, courtesy [Matthew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/52429/matthew), this seems to be the best option:

> I think your brainstorm is the best option. You should get them all
>   child themes and then going forward it will be way less of a hassle to
>   update. It shouldn't take too long. Just figure out which files were
>   customized, through them in a child theme, back up the customized
>   parent theme just in case, and then update the parent theme. Then it
>   should be way better. Not only will you need to do a long manual theme
>   update but in the future you can just update instead of transferring
>   customizations.